# Google Fusion Table Mapping Irregularities

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have developed a web page to look up structural engineering data using Google fusion tables.

http://structurology.com/geodata

The page has data for all areas within the continental US.

I have been testing the application and when I preform a search, I have irregularities in the speed of the results.  Sometimes the data pulls right up, sometimes it takes awhile and then comes up.  Other times it just gives up and says it can't find the data.  When this happens, if you immediately search again, it will find the data.  It seems to be quicker after I have preformed several different searches in a row.

The data sets are pretty large, and I initially tried 7 data subsets and experienced the problems noted above.  Just now, I subdivided these subsets into a total 14 to see if it helped with the problems.  It seems to be a little better, but still experiencing the issues.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many records are in this table? Fusion Tables has a limit to only include the first 100,000 records in query results.

Comment: In total, there are over 611,000.  I initially broke them into 7 subsets and noticed the problems above.  I then divided them in half, making 14 subsets ad still noticed the problems.